# Chrome Extension for Switching Locale (Accept-Languages)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, locale, i18n

Is there a Chrome Extension which can be used to quickly switch between two locales (e.g. English and German) quickly? Some websites detect the user's language using the `Accept-Languages` HTTP-header while not having any UI to configure the desired language. In that case the only way I know of to change the language is to change the mentioned HTTP-header.

Actually, any quick way to switch locales will do. It does not have to be an extension.

Comment: Bookmark `chrome://chrome/settings/languages` and then you just need to Drag and Drop the language to make it default.

Comment: @Serge thanks. I have tested this but without luck. I guess the website decides to always choose priority 1. Makes sense.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Commenter Lamb suggests the following:

> Bookmark chrome://settings/languages and then you just need to
>   Drag and Drop the language to make it default.

I think this is a workable solution.

Comment: note: you have to then click on the 'Display Google Chrome in this Language' button and completely restart Chrome. I found certain extensions were still running in the background and I needed to go to Task Manager to kill all Chrome processes. You can test the date format with this fiddle (switch between US and UK English) http://jsfiddle.net/vRf5B/42/

Comment: you can completely shut down Chrome using "menu > Exit" button. Closing the browser with the X button doesn't kill the background extensions

Comment: use chrome://settings/languages for Chrome/Chromium 81

Answer (score 17):

I have written a Chrome extension which does exactly that: <s>[Quick Language Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie).</s>

Replacement plugin (original link dead)  [Language Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-page-language-sw/mhgjlbolkmcookadjpolimbddngjgbol/related?hl=en)

Comment: Can your extension add languages that *Chrome itself* doesn't directly support? I'm looking for a way to easily add in [locally defined language codes](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/faq.html#26) for localisation tests (testing the process of localisation itself, not localisation to a given language).

Comment: you can add new languages to this extension

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: All the extension does is setting Accept-Languages header, however it does not modify values of JavaScript `navigator.language` and `navigator.languages`.

Comment: it works, it changes `HTTP Header Accept-Language`, read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference/3335420#3335420

Comment: Don't think this works any more. The Accept-Language header is unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

## [Locale Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc)

is the definitive extension for this.

### ✨ Features

- Chrome & [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/locale-switcher/)
- Support for 700+ languages and variations, provided by  [LocalePlanet](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/index.html)
- Per tab basis
- Favorite your most used locales
- Fully shortcut enabled, no mouse needed (*Windows*: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> / *Mac*: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)
- Free Open Source Software on [GitHub](https://github.com/locale-switcher/locale-switcher) under MIT license
- Dark mode

### Stats

- 4.4 ⭐️ Rating
- 40.000+ Users
- 90 KiB size only
- Jan 8, 2019 First Commit
- March 20, 2022 Updated

It seems to be a trustworthy, well maintained extension. Go give it a try!